# Can I say: "only 1 every 170 people do this"?

Tags: word-usage

Is the following sentence correct?

> Only **one every 170 people** do this.

In particular, I'm asking about the usage of the word *every*.

Comment: Most of the time, this usage of "<Number> in every <larger number>" is misleading.  Suppose you have 100 people.  20 of them are redheads, and 80 of them are brunettes.  Suppose (without looking at them) you choose a group of 5 of these people.  Will exactly one out of the 5 be a redhead?  Probably not.  If you choose the five randomly, there is about a 32 percent chance of not choosing a redhead, and about a 26 percent chance of choosing more than one redhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's incorrect. Your sentence is missing *in*. This should be *Only one **in** every 170 people do this.*

*Every* in such sentence would mean that in *one lot* of 170 people, only one person would do that.

The style is quite common while describing the research or statistics. See [here](http://www.cdc.gov/homeandrecreationalsafety/falls/adultfalls.html)

> Each year, one in every three adults age 65 and older falls.

Comment: But you should point out, maybe a bit more clearly, that the OP's sentence is **wrong** because it misses the all-important **in**.

Comment: Interestingly enough, even though _in_ and _out_ might be considered antonyms, we can also use _out_ (if we include _of_ as well): _Only one out of every 170 people will do this_.